# Having different opacity value from the parent div

Tags: jquery, css

`divStatus` has a few controls in it. One is `btnStatus`, which is hidden. On `mouseover` `btnStatus` is displayed and `divStatus's` opacity dropping to `0.5`. I want `btnStatus` to have the opacity `1`. But the code below does not help. `btnStatus` still has the opacity value of `0.5`.

```
$("#divStatus").mouseover(function () {
     $("#divStatus").css("opacity", "0.5");
     $("#btnStatus").show();
     $("#btnStatus").css("opacity", "1");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vuqg97x/)

Comment: show it on JSFiddle.net

Comment: You sould share your html too

Comment: it's like position it's relative to parent opacity : 1 = 100 %, 100% of 50% = 50% :)

Comment: Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/6vuqg97x/

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this in this way. parent opacity value effects all child elements.

But you can put btnStatus out of divStatus and set divStatus as position absolute and place btnStatus over divStatus. you can than control both of opacity values seprately.

`jsfiddle example:`http://jsfiddle.net/cp0c50pd/

Answer (score -1):

I can only advice to use "rgba color" instead of "opacity"

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/z9hmdm7a/

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
```

Comment: Good thinking, but not the same as opacity, in it?